# Number to Date conversion (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, datetime, math, interpolation

I have a number that matches a date and I have no idea how the number is calculated using that date, here are three examples:

```
08/08/2018 12:23     73691437391180 
08/08/2018 12:32     73691437976165 
11/11/2015 14:41     73591349310000
```

If I substract the second from the first, I get the difference of 9.74975 which corresponds to the minutes (and seconds?) passed?

Thanks in advance!

PS: The data is stored in an Oracle Database. It is possible to generate more examples if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone seems to have had some fun dreaming this up. The difference between two values does appear to be milliseconds, but they aren't obvious epoch times.

By a process of elimination it looks like a compound value, as it didn't reliably match as a single value, e.g. dividing by 60*60*24 and variants. It seems to eb based on an epoch time of 0001-01-02 00:00:00 UTC.

The first six digits seem to be the number of days since January 2nd (?) in the year 1 AD/CE. Trying a few possible epoch dates threw up:

```
select date '2018-08-08' - date '0001-01-01' from dual;

DATE'2018-08-08'-DATE'0001-01-01'
---------------------------------
                           736915
```

which was too close to be a coincidence, but was a day out, so it's really based on 0001-01-02, apparently.

The remaining 8 digits seem to be the number of milliseconds after midnight UTC - again just assuming it was from midnight was close, but an hour or two out. So there is also a time zone component, which perhaps make sense and matches your profile location.

This seems to work for the sample values at least:

```
with t (ts) as (
            select timestamp '2018-08-08 11:23:11.180' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2018-08-08 11:32:56.165' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2015-11-11 14:41:50.000' from dual
)
select ts,
  100000000 * extract(day from ts - timestamp '0001-01-02 01:00:00')
  + 3600000 * extract(hour from ts - timestamp '0001-01-02 01:00:00')
    + 60000 * extract(minute from ts - timestamp '0001-01-02 01:00:00')
     + 1000 * extract(second from ts - timestamp '0001-01-02 01:00:00') as n
from t;

             N TS                                         
-------------- -------------------------------------------
73691437391180 2018-08-08 12:23:11.180000000 EUROPE/VIENNA
73691437976165 2018-08-08 12:32:56.165000000 EUROPE/VIENNA
73591349310000 2015-11-11 14:41:50.000000000 EUROPE/VIENNA
```

or to convert the other way, starting from a timestamp rather than a date as there are fractional seconds and time zones involved:

```
with t (ts) as (
            select timestamp '2018-08-08 12:23:11.180 Europe/Vienna' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2018-08-08 12:32:56.165 Europe/Vienna' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2015-11-11 14:41:50.000 Europe/Vienna' from dual
)
select ts,
  100000000 * extract(day from ts - timestamp '0001-01-02 00:00:00 UTC')
  + 3600000 * extract(hour from ts - timestamp '0001-01-02 00:00:00 UTC')
    + 60000 * extract(minute from ts - timestamp '0001-01-02 00:00:00 UTC')
     + 1000 * extract(second from ts - timestamp '0001-01-02 00:00:00 UTC') as n
from t;

TS                                                       N
------------------------------------------- --------------
2018-08-08 12:23:11.180000000 EUROPE/VIENNA 73691437391180
2018-08-08 12:32:56.165000000 EUROPE/VIENNA 73691437976165
2015-11-11 14:41:50.000000000 EUROPE/VIENNA 73591349310000
```

Which is all a bit... unusual.

It's also possible, for the timestamp-to-number conversion, that the starting value is a plain timestamp; this would get the same result via implicit conversion as long as your session was in that time zone.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis!! This helps a lot!